# Can I disable `wp-tinymce.php` load as script?

Tags: tinymce

If you go to your WordPress dashboard trying to edit a page or post. Do you get wp-tinymce.php load.
On some blogs I do, on some, I don't.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://example.com/wp-includes/js/tinymce/wp-tinymce.php?c=1&amp;ver=4403-20160901'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
```

What is the trick? Can I control this somehow?
I am using the latest WordPress installation and checking from the visual mode.

[image]

Comment: you just want the visual tab gone?  I saw this plugin once:  https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-visual-editor-wysiwyg/  I'm sure you could pull the code out.

Answer (score 2):

Seems that the problem is with the virtual site config – the docroot in the fastcgi config. In my example I'm using nginx webserver and PHP7. It has to look like this:

```
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$request_uri;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

Comment: Interesting answer...